# Copying the filename to clipboard in zathura

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, zathura

I am trying to map a key in Zathura that copies the path of the currently opened path to the clipboard. I did this in my `zathurarc`

```
map <C-c> feedkeys ":exec xclip -i -selection clipboard `realpath $FILE`<Return>"
```

But, when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> it doesn't do a thing. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: [`man 5 zathurarc`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/zathurarc.5.html) doesn't list a `feedkeys` function in the list of functions available for mapping. There is an `exec` function, however. Maybe ``map <C-c> exec "xclip -i -selection clipboard `realpath $FILE`"``?

Comment: Zathura seems to lack good documentation. Though `feedkeys` is not there  in the man, it just works in the config file. This doesn't work. The problem is mainly xclip works like this `echo $FILE | xclip -i -selection clipboard`. But, I can't work with this also. @muru

Answer (score 1):

I used a shell script `zathura-copy-path`  (make sure it is available via PATH, and executable)

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1 | xclip -i -selection c
```

In `zathurarc` I added

```
map <C-o> feedkeys ":exec zathura-copy-path $FILE<Return>"
```

Works for me. Also worked just fine with pdf filenames with spaces. Looks like you almost had it, just that zathuras command line isn't sophisticated enough for parsing like a shell.

Answer (score 0):

This will do.

```
:map <C-o> feedkeys ":exec sh -c \"echo $FILE | xclip -i -sel clip\"<Return>"
```

Zathura `exec` adds quote on each words to escape the commands. This breaks the pipe and following `xclip` command. Using shell `sh -c` to group them together avoid this hassle.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. You may want to add some explanation on _why_ you think that helps with the OPs problem (and by that way, _what_ you think the OPs problem actually ist).